# Is it possible to give GCP Postgres users r/w access without the need to query?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is there any other way than using queries to give GCP users r/w access to GCP postgresql DBs? I read about the **Cloud SQL IAM database authentication** but that only gives the user the ability to connect the DB and nothing more. For r/w permissions, there's a need to use queries to GRANT access. We have a lot of people requesting access to the DBs ( well, and a lot of DBs)and connecting to the DB and using a grant query each time is really time consuming.

Ideally I had something like [this feature](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-23-how-to-add-aad-security-groups-to-azure-sql/ba-p/368866) in Azure in mind( you can create r/w security groups and map the r/w permissions to them, and add users to those groups). I would be really happy and thankful to know if there's any other way that I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is no. I've found that my question has being asked before: [Cloud SQL Postgres - Managing Database Users, Best Practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237607/cloud-sql-postgres-managing-database-users-best-practices)

Comment: If your question has already been answered, it's better to close this as a duplicate of that one

Comment: Hey hey, actually I can't close this as a duplicate. I don't have enough rep. I'll accept my answer tomorrow so that it will be closed (it doesn't let me accept it now)

Comment: Accepting the answer won't close it. I'll vote to close as a duplicate and you should be able to confirm that